# ¿como puedo devolver un procedimiento en una función?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, function

Buen día tengo una duda, tengo un procedimiento que devuelve unos datos como si fuera una tabla, pero si le quiero aplicar un filtro no puedo, entonces se me ocurrio que una función ejecute dicho procedimiento y asi poder aplicarle filtros
[image: [![esto devuelve el procedimiento][1]][1], [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lsWi.png]
se ocupan los filtros por que esta info la agarro de unos archivos y algunos tienen millones de registros, esta es la función que se me ocurrio

```
(
 @ipSer varchar(15)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
declare @proc table = Exec cargarResumen @ipServidor = @ipSer
RETURN (@proc)
GO
```

si alguien tiene una idea mejor, estaría feliz que la compartieran

Comment: No seria mejor que generes una copia de ese sp, o adaptarlo agregando los parámetros para los filtros que necesitas, ya que cada consulta que generes tendrá que procesar esos millones de registros para que al final tu apliques un filtro y te regrese solo 2 o 3 registros.

Comment: Se puede hacer que esos filtros sean opcionales? osea que no de a fuerzas tengan que ser todos los parametros a la hora de llamar el procedimiento

Comment: Si se puede, unicamente tienes que agregar un valor predeterminado a el parámetro y es el que tomara cuando no se envié en una llamada, ej `@param1 as int = 0`, [optional-vs-required-parameters](https://sqlstudies.com/2019/07/29/optional-vs-required-parameters-in-stored-procedures/)

Comment: No puedes invocar un SP dentro de una función, o al menos de una forma natural.